# I can't find element in a HTML file with XPath

Tags: xpath

I am trying to get the name and the price information from this website with XPath. When i write my XPath expression down in the search bar it locates correctly in the chrome. But in VSC it doesn't work. I get nameHtml is null error. This is the only element that has `style__Text-sc-__sc-1nwjacj-0 iwTTHJ sc-dd9e2587-8 dsYcan` class. Is there a problem with my expression or the code ?
Thanks

[image: the website i want to scrape informations from]

my code:

```
public class Main {

public static HtmlPage getDocument(String url) {
    HtmlPage page = null;
    try (final WebClient webClient = new WebClient()) {
        webClient.getOptions().setCssEnabled(false);
        webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(false);
        page = webClient.getPage(url);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return page;
}



public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

   

    WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
    webClient.getOptions().setCssEnabled(false);
    webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(false);



    HtmlPage page = getDocument("https://getir.com/en/category/fruits-veg-tBYm30SlS9/");
    HtmlElement nameHtml = page.getFirstByXPath("//div[@class = 'style__Text-sc-__sc-1nwjacj-0 iwTTHJ sc-dd9e2587-8 dsYcan']");
    
    System.out.println(nameHtml.asNormalizedText());}
```

Comment: The link (https://getir.com/en/category/fruits-veg-tBYm30SlS9/) returns 403 error. It would help if you can share the HTML for the page or fix the permission issue so that people can access the page.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try

//*[contains(text(),'₺')]